# Removing specific list-style's with multiple ul's

Tags: css

Let's say as an example, I have two lists.

1st:

```
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
<li>TEST 5</li>
<li>TEST 6</li>
<li>TEST 7</li>
</ul>
```

2nd:

```
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to remove the list-style (just the icon) from TEST 4 in the first list and the list-style (again, just the icon) from TEST 3 from the second list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here - http://jsfiddle.net/5d4TU/5/. I explained this before that if the ul's were only one apart it would work.

Comment: Can you change/amend the HTML, or does it have to remain without either an `id` or a `class`? And why are you asking this question; the previous question you asked seems incredibly close to being a duplicate.

Comment: Is it important that you have 1, 2, or N lists on your page? You can simply ask "how can I change the style of the Nth item in my list" and apply the answer twice for different values of N.

Comment: @David Thomas. I created anew question because Zenith said it was different from my initial question.

Comment: Well, I (clearly) disagree with that; I think that adding the case pf the second list clarifies your intent as regards the first. However my voting to close isn't final, and relies on others agreeing (and, subsequently, could be reopened by yet others). But your question seems to boil down to: 'how do I remove the disc from the penultimate list-item?' Which is addressed by *both* questions.

Comment: @DavidThomas I asked him because in his first question, he asked how to remove the 6th element, so I answered and thought that was that. If you check the comments on my answer there, you'll see it quickly diverted and I tried to edit best I could but it seemed to keep changing. In fact, even this question seems different to what was asked of me in the comments..

Comment: I'll just remove this question.

Comment: @ChrisBrighton Your original question was poorly asked (and really, so is this one).  "I want to remove the 6th element of the list" is quite different from "I want to remove the middle element from a dynamic list that might have 12 items in it".  The original should have been clarified rather than creating a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d4TU/6/)

Using `nth-last-child(2)` is one option, as shown here.

---

```
li:nth-last-child(2) {
   list-style-type: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li style='list-style-type:none;'>TEST 2</li>
<li>TEST 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>TEST 1</li>
<li>TEST 2</li>
<li style='list-style-type:none;'>TEST 3</li>
<li>TEST 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm obviously not explaining myself enough but this is exactly what I want but in CSS. Might just do it in-line. Thanks.

Comment: you could create a class in your external css file,

.removeItemStyle {
list-style-type:none;
}
then add it to the list items you don't want to show bullet points on.
<li class='removeItemStyle'>TEST 2</li>

Comment: Yes, that's a brilliant idea. I will do that. Many thanks.